# Sorting excel columns by value using Openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I did this in pandas with 2 lines of code but can't find an equivalent in Openpyxl, sadly I can't use pandas for this project.
My pandas code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test2.xlsx')
first_n_rows = df.sort_values(by=['Min tries', 'Total min tries'], ascending=[True, False]).head(5)
```

I am trying to sort scores for a game by number of Minimum tries, and if 2 users have same number of Min tries, then sort by Total min tries  descending.

Comment: Pandas is really an in-memory database. You can use sqlite (in the standard library) to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl is used to read and write Excel files.
You can do it this way with win32com (if pandas is not allowed):

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('MyWorkbook.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')

ws.Range('A2:A9').Sort(Key1=ws.Range('A1'), Key2=ws.Range('A1'), Order1=1, Order2=0, Orientation=1)
```

Change the pointer according to your excel